# How to track the trace of a file through commits in the forward direction in a git repository?

Tags: git, git-log, git-rev-list

Suppose we have a file *F* in a certain commit *C*. Given a future commit *C'*, what is the best way to deduce the list of files in *C'* that are derived from *F*?

A file can be modified, renamed, moved, copied, deleted, split and merged several times in any order on its journey from one commit to another.

I want to determine the final list of files - which can be empty - that are "derived" from the original file through such operations, ideally using plumbing commands of git.

Yes, there is no way to reliably say wether a file is split, merged, moved or copied for certain. But the algorithm that is used in git-log or git-blame for the same purposes should be ok. (Thanks @SpaceKatt).

**TL;DR** I want a function that produces the following Output given the Input:

```
Input: {F, C, C'}
  C is an earlier commit.
  C' is a later commit (and C is reachable from C')
  F is a file in C

Output: {F1', F2', F3', ...}
  Fx's are list of files in C' that are derived from F
```

**Note**: If It was the opposite problem (i.e finding history of a file) a solution could probably be derived using `git-log` or `git-blame`, although I am not aware of a perfect solution (not involving porcelain) for that either.

Comment: Well there's no such thing as "forward" in Git. Pointers point only backward.

Comment: Do you mean that a file can't be traced from parent to child? @matt

Comment: generally, there is no way to reliably say whether a file has been copied, split, or merged. there are special situations where you may, however these are the exception - not the rule

Comment: Yes, there is no perfect way to say it for certain. But a solution that is as reliable as git-log or git-blame for copy, split, merge detection is enough for my case. @SpaceKatt

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that Git can only go backwards, not forwards (as [matt noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68671049/how-to-track-the-trace-of-a-file-through-commits-in-the-forward-direction-in-a-g#comment121359640_68671049)).

The workaround for this is simple: go backwards.  Let's say you have a branch name *BR* that identifies some final commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H ... <-Z   <--BR
```

and you wish to "go forward from G".  Start by listing out every commit *backwards*, from `Z` on:

```
git rev-list BR
```

When you reach commit `G`, stop.  Take the list of hash IDs you just generated, and now you can work through them one pair at a time:

```
(H, G)
(I, H)
(...)
(Z, Y)
```

Note that `git blame --reverse` already "knows how to do this", as it were, but still needs both *end-points*, i.e., you have to locate `Z`, assuming you want to go forward to `Z`.  But you'll have to pick the *file names* yourself, which is kind of the problem.  (You could run it once for every file in `Z`, automatedly; this will be slow.)  There is no good answer to this, at least not today.